# show interfaces in iptables -L

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

Is there a way to show the network interfaces via `iptables -L` in Ubuntu 12.04?

When I execute an `iptables -L` I get an output like this :

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination       
...
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0     
...
```

which is somehow misleading. First I was thinking, great rule, allows everything until I discovered that this rule is bound to interface localhost.

Is there a way to get an overview which shows the rules and the interfaces at once?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Add `-v` for the verbose mode.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
39050 4448K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 6595  544K ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  419 15084 ACCEPT     2    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Even better, change the command to `-S` for plain mode:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p igmp -j ACCEPT
```